# c# winforms flowlayoutpanel wrap contents

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem with wrap contents in flowlayoutpanel control. Before i enable wrap content grid of buttons is listed good. When i enable `Autoscroll` and change `FlowDirection` my butons was showed vertical not as grid like above buttons.
White buttons need to be showed as above blue buttons. Red boxes explain how to loop it. But when i disable `Wrap contents` everything work good. 
What can be problem ?
 Check screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I can only guess, but it looks to me as though you've set the flow direction to `TopDown`. Since you've enabled `AutoScroll`, the panel will implement a vertical scroll bar instead of wrapping back to the top.

Try the following:

```
myFlowPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider voting it as your accepted answer, thank you.